# Accessing Two dimensional array with pointers giving error

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
Int arr[2][4], *p; p = &arr[0][0]; 
*(p + 2) = 10; //ok 
*(p + 5) = 20;// ok 
*(*(arr + 1) + 3) = 15;//ok 
*(*(p + 1) + 3) = 15;// error
```

I don't understand why the last one gives me an error and the one before that is fine. 
`p` is equal to `arr`, so why its not working?

Comment: type of `*(p + 1)` is `Int`, not pointer. So `*(p + 1) + 3` can't dereference.

Comment: As a multidimensional array, `arr` is an array *of arrays*.  When it decays to a pointer to its first element, that pointer is a pointer to an array (`Int (*)[4]`).  If you dereference such a pointer, you get an array, which can itself decay to a pointer, in this case to `Int`.  Variable `p`, on the other hand, is a pointer to `Int`.  You can dereference it to get an `Int`, but you cannot further dereference that result, because it is not a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`arr` is of type `int (*)[4]` in the expression `*(*(arr + 1) + 3) = 15;` and `*(arr + 1)` of type `int *` (after array to pointer conversion) and therefore dereference operator can be applied on it.  While on the other hand `p` is of type `int *`. `*(p + 1)` is of type `int` and you can't apply a dereference operator on it.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in expressions are converted to pointers to their first elements.

Thus the array `arr` in the expression (in subexpression `arr + 1`)`*(*(arr + 1) + 3)` is converted to a pointer of type `int ( * )[4]` . In turn the subexpression `arr + 1` also has the same type. The subexpression `*(arr + 1)`  yields an object of type `int[4]` that in turn is converted to pointer to its first element and has type `int *`. So you may dereference this pointer like

```
*(*(arr + 1) + 3) = 15;//ok
```

The pointer `p` has type `int *` So this subexpression `*(p + 1)` has type `int` and may not be further dereferenced.

Compare these statements written one below the other

```
  *(p + 2) = 10;  
*(*(p + 1) + 3) = 15;
```

From the first statement it is seen that `*(p + 2)` has type `int`. So it does not male sense to dereference the expression `*(p + 1) + 3` that also has type `int`.